Drag Gesture to connect Circles in SwiftUI
I'm trying a POC to implement dragging between circles (similar to the Android pattern lock screen back in the day) but in SwiftUI and I'm learning how to use DragGestures() to achieve this.
I started by creating a simple 3 x 3 grid and setting the 'correct path drag' sequence as (0, 3, 6) this is referring to the index positions of the circles in the grid so that when the user drags the circles in this sequence, the paths would connect(like the next pic), else if the wrong circle was chosen and dragged, the path will not connect.


I've been able to start a drag from each circle's center, and defined the logic for onChanged and onEnded but I'm unable to get the path to join as of now, some assistance here would be greatly appreciated, this is my own implementation below:
import SwiftUI

struct Line: Hashable {
    var start: CGPoint
    var end: CGPoint
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(start.x)
        hasher.combine(start.y)
        hasher.combine(end.x)
        hasher.combine(end.y)
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: Line, rhs: Line) -> Bool {
        return lhs.start == rhs.start && lhs.end == rhs.end
    }
}

//collect circle positions
struct CirclePositionsKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: [Int: CGPoint] { [:] }
    
    static func reduce(value: inout [Int : CGPoint], nextValue: () -> [Int : CGPoint]) {
        value.merge(nextValue(), uniquingKeysWith: { $1 })
    }
}

struct LineDragGesture: View {
    
    @State private var lines: [Line] = [] 
    @State private var currentDragPoint: CGPoint? = nil
    @State private var selectedCircleIndex: Int? 
    @State private var selectedCirclePosition: CGPoint? 
    
    @State private var correctPaths: [Int] = [0, 3, 6] // Correct path sequence
    @State private var currentPathIndex: Int = 0 
    
    @State private var circlePositions: [Int: CGPoint] = [:] 
    
    @State private var correctCircleIndex = 0
    @State private var correctCirclePosition: CGPoint = .zero
    
    @State private var nextCorrectCircleIndex = 0
    @State private var nextCorrectCirclePosition: CGPoint = .zero
    
    var sortedCoordinates: [(key: Int, value: CGPoint)] {
        circlePositions.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key})
    }
    
    let columns: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Draw each completed line
            ForEach(lines, id: \.self) { line in
                Path { path in
                    path.move(to: line.start)
                    path.addLine(to: line.end)
                }
                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 6)
            }
            
            // Draw the line from the chosen circle to the current drag point
            if let currentDragPoint = currentDragPoint, let startingIndex = selectedCircleIndex {
                Path { path in
                    path.move(to: circlePositions[startingIndex] ?? .zero)
                    path.addLine(to: currentDragPoint)
                }
                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 6)
            }
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(0..<9) { index in
                    GeometryReader { geo in
                        let frame = geo.frame(in: .named("GridContainer"))
                        let center = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .preference(key: CirclePositionsKey.self, value: [
                                    index : center
                                ])
                                .gesture(
                                    DragGesture()
                                        .onChanged { value in
                                            // If the user starts dragging from the correct circle in the sequence
                                            if selectedCircleIndex == nil {
                                                selectedCircleIndex = index
                                                selectedCirclePosition = sortedCoordinates[index].value
                                            }
                                            
                                            // Calculate the current drag point based on the initial circle's position
                                            if let startingPos = selectedCirclePosition {
                                                currentDragPoint = CGPoint(
                                                    x: startingPos.x + value.translation.width,
                                                    y: startingPos.y + value.translation.height
                                                )
                                            }
                                        }
                                        .onEnded { value in
                                            guard let startingIndex = selectedCircleIndex,
                                                  let draggedPoint = currentDragPoint else { return }
                                            
                                            // Check if the next point in the path is correct and if user is dragging from correct circle
                                            if selectedCircleIndex == correctCircleIndex,
                                               distance(from: draggedPoint, to: nextCorrectCirclePosition) <= 25 {
                                                // Append line if correct next point is reached
                                                lines.append(Line(start: circlePositions[startingIndex]!, end: nextCorrectCirclePosition))
                                                removeCorrectlyGuessed()
                                                setNextCorrectCircle()
                                            }
                                            
                                            // Reset the drag point and the starting circle index
                                            currentDragPoint = nil
                                            selectedCircleIndex = nil
                                            selectedCirclePosition = nil
                                        }
                                )
                        }
                        // .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(CirclePositionsKey.self) { value in
            circlePositions = value
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "GridContainer")
        .onAppear {
            let correctPoint = getFirstCorrectCircle()
            if let correctPoint {
                correctCircleIndex = correctPoint.0
                correctCirclePosition = correctPoint.1
            }
            
            let nextCorrectPoint = getNextCircle()
            if let nextCorrectPoint {
                correctCircleIndex = nextCorrectPoint.0
                correctCirclePosition = nextCorrectPoint.1
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Helper function to calculate distance between two points
    private func distance(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(pow(from.x - to.x, 2) + pow(from.y - to.y, 2))
    }
    
    //on load set first correct circle
    private func getFirstCorrectCircle() -> (Int, CGPoint)? {
        guard let pathNum = correctPaths.first else { return nil }
        let position = sortedCoordinates[pathNum].value
        return (pathNum, position)
    }
    
    
    private func getNextCircle() -> (Int, CGPoint)? {
        guard correctPaths.count > 1 else { return nil }
        let pathNum = correctPaths[1]
        let position = sortedCoordinates[pathNum].value
        return (pathNum, position)
        
    }
    
    private func setNextCorrectCircle() {
        guard let nextPosition = getNextCircle() else { return }
        correctCircleIndex = nextPosition.0
        correctCirclePosition = nextPosition.1
    }
    
    private func removeCorrectlyGuessed() {
        guard !correctPaths.isEmpty else { return }
        correctPaths.removeFirst()
    }
}

#Preview {
    LineDragGesture()
}


This post might help: Is it possible to detect which View currently falls under the location of a DragGesture?

The answer to Is it possible to detect which View currently falls under the location of a DragGesture? illustrates a technique that can be used for detecting when a shape is under a drag gesture (it was my answer).
You are using a similar technique. But instead of adding a drag gesture to each circle, try using just one drag gesture for the whole grid.
Other suggestions:

Use a GestureState state variable to record the drag location. This automatically resets at end of drag.

Instead of mutating the array of correct paths (the target sequence), define it as constant with let. Then use a separate state variable to save the array of discovered circles.

You are already using a state variable to record the current position. A didSet setter observer function can be attached to this variable. The logic for extending the array of discovered circles can then be implemented here.

Use a Canvas in the background to draw the lines between discovered circles.

If the spacing between circles is known then the position of the middle of a circle can be computed quite easily by dividing up the total width and height of the grid. However, it is important to set the horizontal spacing between GridItem, otherwise the LazyVGrid uses its own default spacing.

Use a Namespace to name the coordinate space. This prevents the name from being mistyped.


struct LineDragGesture: View {
    let circleSize: CGFloat = 50
    let gridSpacing: CGFloat = 20
    let correctPaths: [Int] = [0, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 1, 2, 4] // Correct path sequence
    let columns: [GridItem]

    @Namespace private var coordinateSpace
    @GestureState private var currentDragPoint = CGPoint.zero
    @State private var discoveredCircles = [Int]()
    @State private var selectedCircleIndex: Int? {
        didSet {
            if let selectedCircleIndex,
               discoveredCircles.count < correctPaths.count,
               selectedCircleIndex == correctPaths[discoveredCircles.count] {
                discoveredCircles.append(selectedCircleIndex)
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        self.columns = [
            GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: gridSpacing),
            GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: gridSpacing),
            GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: gridSpacing)
        ]
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 80) {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: gridSpacing) {
                ForEach(0..<9) { index in
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: circleSize, height: circleSize)
                        .background { dragDetector(circleIndex: index ) }
                }
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: coordinateSpace)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .named(coordinateSpace))
                    .updating($currentDragPoint) { val, state, trans in
                        state = val.location
                    }
                    .onEnded { val in
                        selectedCircleIndex = nil
                    }
            )
            .background { joinedCircles }

            Button("Reset") {
                discoveredCircles.removeAll()
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
    }

    private func dragDetector(circleIndex: Int) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let frame = proxy.frame(in: .named(coordinateSpace))
            let isDragLocationInsideFrame = frame.contains(currentDragPoint)
            let isDragLocationInsideCircle = isDragLocationInsideFrame &&
                Circle().path(in: frame).contains(currentDragPoint)
            Color.clear
                .onChange(of: isDragLocationInsideCircle) { oldVal, newVal in
                    if currentDragPoint != .zero {
                        selectedCircleIndex = newVal ? circleIndex : nil
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private var joinedCircles: some View {
        Canvas { ctx, size in
            if !discoveredCircles.isEmpty {
                var path = Path()
                for (i, circleIndex) in discoveredCircles.enumerated() {
                    let point = circlePosition(circleIndex: circleIndex, gridSize: size)
                    if i == 0 {
                        path.move(to: point)
                    } else {
                        path.addLine(to: point)
                    }
                }
                if currentDragPoint != .zero {
                    path.addLine(to: currentDragPoint)
                }
                ctx.stroke(path, with: .color(.secondary), style: .init(lineWidth: 6, lineCap: .round))
            }
        }
    }

    private func circlePosition(circleIndex: Int, gridSize: CGSize) -> CGPoint {
        let cellWidth = (gridSize.width + gridSpacing) / 3
        let cellHeight = (gridSize.height + gridSpacing) / 3
        let row = circleIndex / 3
        let col = circleIndex % 3
        let x = (cellWidth * CGFloat(col)) + (cellWidth / 2) - (gridSpacing / 2)
        let y = (cellHeight * CGFloat(row)) + (cellHeight / 2) - (gridSpacing / 2)
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
}



Thank you, this was very insightful and completely changed my thinking and approach of how to go about this. Learnt GestureState, something new for me. Thanks, I have something to work with and can tweak my use case now :)
